# Unity variable of .. has not been assigned

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to make enemy fire at me. My script looks good but it says target variable has not been assigned. In inspector I selected my player object into target slot. But it keep saying the same error.

```
public GameObject AntagonisticElement;
public GameObject Target;
public float bulletSpeed;
public float enemySpeed;
public float bulletDestroyTime;
public GameObject explsn;
public GameObject bulletPrefab;
public Transform bulletSpawn;

Vector3 pos;

public float min = 20;
public float max = 10;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Tank");
}    
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    transform.LookAt(Target.transform.position);

    if (Vector3.Distance(AntagonisticElement.transform.position, Target.transform.position) >= min)
    {
        AntagonisticElement.transform.position += AntagonisticElement.transform.forward * 4 * Time.deltaTime;

    }
    if (Vector3.Distance(AntagonisticElement.transform.position, Target.transform.position) <= max)
    {
        shootAt();
    }

}

void shootAt()
{

    Instantiate(explsn, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.transform.rotation);
    var bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletSpawn.position, bulletSpawn.rotation);
    bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = bullet.transform.forward * bulletSpeed;

}
```

Comment: You said that you assign manually the Prefab into the Target slot in the editor, why do you call ``Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Tank");`` in the start method then ? 
Maybe Unity doesn't find any gameObject with that tag in your hierarchy.

Comment: i also deleted it but again same error

Comment: On which line does it throws the error ?

Comment: transform.LookAt(Target.transform.position);

Comment: Then I don't really see any error, the variable is not assigned, take a closer look to the inspector, is your variable really assigned in the inspector ?

Comment: i clicked on script then in inspector panel clicked target slot and then chose an asset from opened window "select asset" is it correct?

Comment: You clicked on the script in your project window ? 
Then it is not correct, you need to select the GameObject in the Hierarchy that contains the script and then drag&drop your prefab into the Target Slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this error because the Target field is not assigned to a GameObject.

To assign a reference to a `MonoBehaviour` script, do the following :

- Select the `GameObject` with the script attached to it from your hierarchy.
- In the inspector window, locate the Target slot.
- Drag & Drop the prefab into the slot or click on the circle next to it to select from Project or Hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You override it in Start Function. Remove this line or be sure you have Tank tag for it.
You can just drag the target gameObject and drop it on the target field

> ```
> Target = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Tank");
> ```

Comment: OP said he removed this line from his code and still having the exception.

Comment: guys i have solved theproblem thanks to all. but now problem is bigger it doesnt fire i dont know why